# Intersect tool unable to find feature class in Python script

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, intersect

I keep receiving this error: [image]

from this piece of my script:

```
# Process: Clip
arcpy.Clip_analysis(Full_Grid, NAR_U9, os.path.join(Output_Folder, 
"Cruise_Grid_U9"), "")

Cruise_Grid_U9 = os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Grid_U9")

# Process: Intersect
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(Cruise_Grid_U9, os.path.join(Output_Folder, 
"Plots_Before_Dissolve_DELETE.shp"), "NO_FID", "", "POINT")
```

I can't understand why it's unable to find the feature used for the intersect. In the error message there is a '#' at the end of the file path. Is this just part of the error message or is it actually trying to look for that file path?

Comment: it's a shapefile

Comment: I see it now. I missed the file extension on the clip output and the variable. Thanks! If you answer the question I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filepath in your code and on disk needs to have a .shp file extension.